# Ways to demonstrate ("show-off") contributions as an undergraduate in research

Tags: publications, phd, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

I am an undergraduate   CS  student at a US college. Before this summer, I contacted a professor in Game Research and was offered the opportunity to work with one of his PhD students. Currently, I am focusing solely on this opportunity. I wrote lots of code and helped the PhD student run experiments and collect data.

The best outcome of this opportunity would be a publication and a recommendation letter. However, I am only 50% confident that I will be able to get one of the two at the end.

**Are there other practical ways for me to demonstrate my contribution (that can help with future applications)?**

**Any other advice would help too.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A recommendation letter is the way you get credit for this kind of work. I'm not sure why you think you're only 50% likely to get a letter out of this, it would be very unusual for a professor to be willing to work on a research project with you but to not be willing to write a letter for you.  As long as you're taking it seriously and professionally I think you should have close to a 100% chance of getting a letter out of it.

Comment: The reason why I think I'm only 50% likely to get a recommendation letter is this: I meet with the professor at most once (about 20 minutes) per two weeks, and I am not sure whether a total of 4-5 meetings and some email exchanges suffice for a recommendation letter. I do meet much more frequently with the PhD student though.

Comment: I am thinking about meeting more frequently with the professor. However, as I mentioned in the question, my job is to run experiments. I find it hard to start a causal conversation without priming it with some (interesting) results.

Comment: The professor can talk to the graduate student to learn more to write the letter.  If you’re worried you can tell the professor that you’re hoping for a letter and ask whether things are going well for that so far. But everything you say sounds pretty normal to me.

Comment: @ZhihanYang Here's an anecdote. When I was applying for PhD, I didn't ask for a recommendation from a professor I worked with for the very same reason you described. When they found out that I was applying for PhD, they were very surprised that I didn't ask them for a recommendation, mentioning that they would have written a very good letter for me.

Comment: The lesson for us faculty is to be proactive and make sure that we tell our research advisees that we’d be happy to write them a letter if they decide they want to ask.